# SSIS 2008 R2 - How to dynamically change connections during runtime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I am using SQL Server SSIS 2008 R2.

I want to dynamically change a connection manager for OLEDB during runtime to point at a database determined during the running of the package.

This means that I cannot use configuration files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use expressions and populate a variable with the connection property you would like to change.  In the properties of each object, there is a field called expressions, which you can open up and dynamically change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Use expressions in the connection manager properties windows to construct the value in runtime

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/03/11/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Setting-expressions.aspx